# Removing Duplicate columns while doing pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
id   product_1   product_2   count  
1        100       200          10
2        200       600          20
3        100       500          30
4        400       100          40
5        500       700          50
6        200       500          60
7        100       400          70
```

also  i have another table in dataframe df2

```
product    price
100         5
200         10
300         15
400         20
500         25
600         30
700         35
```

i wanted to merge `df2` with `df1` such that i get price_x and price_y as columns

and then again `divide price_y/price_x` to get final column as `perc_diff`.

so i tried to do merge using.

```
# Add prices for products 1 and 2
df3 = (df1.
       merge(df2, left_on='product_1', right_on='product').
       merge(df2, left_on='product_2', right_on='product'))

# Calculate the percent difference
df3['perc_diff'] = (df3.price_y - df3.price_x) / df3.price_x
```

But when i did merge i got multiple columns of `product_1` and `product_2`

for eg. my `df3.head(1)` after merging is:

```
id  product_1   product_2   count  product_1   product_2   price_x   price_y 
1       100       200         10    100          200          5        10
```

So how do i remove these multiple column's of `product_1` &  `product_2` while merging or after merging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df2_ = df2.set_index('product')
df3 = df.join(df2_, on='product_1') \
        .join(df2_, on='product_2', lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')

df3.assign(perc_diff=df3.price_y.div(df3.price_x).sub(1))
```

[image]

Comment: is merge faster or join for a huge dataset(in Gb's)

Comment: I'd make a solid guess they are about the same.

Answer (score 2):

For removing column is necessary `rename`:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='product_1', right_on='product') \
         .merge(df2.rename(columns={'product':'product_2'}), on='product_2')

#borrow from piRSquared solution
df3 = df3.assign(perc_diff=df3.price_y.div(df3.price_x).sub(1))
print (df3)
   id  product_1  product_2  count  product  price_x  price_y  perc_diff
0   1        100        200     10      100        5       10       1.00
1   3        100        500     30      100        5       25       4.00
2   6        200        500     60      200       10       25       1.50
3   7        100        400     70      100        5       20       3.00
4   2        200        600     20      200       10       30       2.00
5   4        400        100     40      400       20        5      -0.75
6   5        500        700     50      500       25       35       0.40
```